# Python: make an array to matrix (one-hot encoding)

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I have an array of dimension n, with two values 0 and 1. Like:

```
[0,1,1,0,1]
```

I would like to make it a nx2 matrix, first column indicate if the value is 0, and the second column indicates if the value is 1. The above array should look like:

```
[[1,0],
 [0,1],
 [0,1],
 [1,0],
 [0,1]]
```

what would be the easiest way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = np.array([0,1,1,0,1])
newA = A[:, None]                       # create a new axis
np.concatenate([1-newA, newA], axis=1)

array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Though you should have tried something by yourself before asking, here is the simple solution

```
source = [0,1,1,0,1]
[[1-v, v] for v in source]
```